# Passing data from flask to HTML

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to pass a list of paths to HTML, but for some reason the output is a blank HTML page. below are my HTML and python code. 
I am new to web dev. so i am struggling here.

here is my python code from where i am extracting the path of dir containing .md files and it will return a list of dir paths and that i have to show through the template.

```
from flask import Flask,render_template, request, redirect, url_for
from git import Repo
import os
from urllib.parse import urlparse
from pathlib import Path

app = Flask(__name__)

def parser(full_path):

path = full_path

files = []
for r, d, f in os.walk(path):
    for file in f:
        if '.md' in file:
            if 'README.md' not in file:

                root = r.replace(path,"")
                url_path = root + "/" + file.replace('.md', '')
                path = str(url_path)
                files.append(path)
return files

def create_dir(gh_url):
#    from ipdb import set_trace;set_trace()
git_url = gh_url

git_dir = git_url.strip('/').split('/')
git_dir = git_dir[-1]

if not os.path.exists(git_dir):
    os.mkdir(git_dir)

home = Path(Path.home())
new_dir = "new_dir"

if not os.path.exists(new_dir):
    os.mkdir(new_dir)

path = os.path.join(home, new_dir)

full_path = os.path.join(path, git_dir)

Repo.clone_from(git_url, full_path)

return parser(full_path)

@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def index():
files = []
if request.method == 'POST':
    gh_url  = request.form['gh_url']

    if len(gh_url) == 0:
        message = "Please enter the github repo"
    else:
        files = create_dir(gh_url)
return render_template('index.html', files=files)                

app.run(debug=True)
```

The index.html page is

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>{% block title %}Enter the Github repository{% endblock %}</title>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
 {% for name in files %}
 <li>{{ name }}</li>
 {% endfor %}
</ul>

<ol>
 {% for name in files %}
 <li>{{ name }}</li>
 {% endfor %}
</ol>
</body>
</html>
```

base.html is

```
{% block title %}Raw Form Example{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<form method = "POST">
    <p>
        <label for="gh-label">GitHub URL</label>
        <input id="gh-url" name="gh_url" type="text">
    </p>

    <input type="submit" value="Show">
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: You pass `files` to `render_template('index.html', files=files)` which can be None, if `len(gh_url) != 0`, it's not so good for your application (`UnboundLocalError: local variable 'files' referenced before assignment`). Are you going to fix it?

Comment: Hi, yes I'm fixing it

Comment: If you fix this and your templates - it must get better.
Also pay attention to what is returned by webserver (inspect page source or use curl). Malformed page will look like blank too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstrly you should move `{% extends 'base.html' %}` from `index.html` to `base.html` and then rename index.html to base.html and base.html to index.html.

Please, read [documentation about template inheritance](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/templateinheritance/) carefully.

Then your the identation of your python code is wrong and it creates difficulties to reproduce your example.